# C# Queue Display implementation - Print contents without modifying nodes

Tags: c#, printing, linked-list, queue

So I have my code implementing Queue in a Linked List version. Everything working, but the display method. I have spent days trying to figure out the right way to display the contents of the nodes in my Queue, without modifying the nodes or queue itself.

This is my code:

```
public class QueueNode
    {        
        private Object bike;
        private QueueNode next;

        public QueueNode(Object bike)
        {
            this.bike = bike;
            next = null;            
        }

        public Object Bike //Content
        {
            get
            {
                return bike;
            }
            set
            {
                bike = value;
            }
        }

        public QueueNode Next //Pointer
        {
            get
            {
                return next;
            }
            set
            {
                next = value;
            }
        }

        
    }  // end of QueueNode

// This class inherits the interface IQueue, that uses these methods, not relevant here. 
    public class CircularQueue : IQueue 
    {
        private int capacity = Int32.MaxValue;
        private int count = 0;
        private QueueNode tail = null; //Node

        public int Capacity
        {
            get
            {
                return capacity;
            }
        }

        public int Count
        {
            get
            {
                return count;
            }
        }

        public bool IsEmpty()
        {
            return count == 0;
        }


        public bool IsFull()
        {
            return count == capacity;
        }

        public void Enqueue(Object item)
        {
            // check the pre-condition
            if (!IsFull())
            {
                QueueNode aNode = new QueueNode(item);
                if (count == 0) //special case: the queue is empty
                {
                    tail = aNode;
                    tail.Next = tail;
                }
                else //general case
                {
                    aNode.Next = tail.Next;
                    tail.Next = aNode;
                    tail = aNode;
                }
                count++;
            }
        }

        public Object Dequeue()
        {
            // check the pre-condition
            if (!IsEmpty())
            {
                Object data;
                if (count == 1) //special case: the queue has only 1 item
                {
                    data = tail.Bike;
                    tail = null;
                }
                else //general case
                {
                    data = tail.Next.Bike;
                    tail.Next = tail.Next.Next;
                }
                count--;
                return data;
            }
            else
                return null;
        }
```

**MY PROBLEM**: I created this code to display the content of the Nodes (and it display them all), but it ends up modifying the contents, placing the same value in every single node at the end of the task.

```
        /*public void DisplayBikes()
        {
            if (!IsEmpty())
            {
                Object data;
                for(int i = 0; i <count; i++)
                {
                    data = tail.Next.Bike;
                    Console.WriteLine(data);                    
                    tail.Next = tail.Next.Next;
                }                
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Sorry. There are no Bikes available");
        }*/
```

Then I went a bit adventurous, and created a temporary Node to display the contents of all the Nodes in my Queue, but ended up being a messed up thing. I got this message:

*System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'*

*tail was null.*

So, at this point I have zero idea on how to do this. I know I'm pretty close, but I don't know what I'm missing here, to make this code print the contents of my Nodes....
HELP PLEASE!

```
        public void DisplayBikes()
        {
            int c = count;
            QueueNode temp = tail.Next;
            if(!isFull())
            {
              while(c > 0)
              {                
                  Console.WriteLine(temp.Bike);
                  temp = tail.Next.Next;
                  c--;
              }
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Sorry. There are no Bikes available");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED** myself.

```
public void DisplayBikes()
        {
            int c = count;
            QueueNode temp = tail.Next;
            if(!isFull())
            {
              while(c > 0)
              {                
                  Console.WriteLine(temp.Bike);
                  temp = temp.Next; //Here. I needed to iterate over the same node
                  c--;
              }
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Sorry. There are no Bikes available");
        }
```

That was it. No one dared to help.... So, thank you guys >:(